# How to test if the input value contain string

Tags: regex, html

In my html 5 page, I want to force the user to add in the end of his login the ".app" string.
Do you know how I can make that ?

My current code:

```
<input type="text" name="user_login" placeholder="firstname.app" required style="width:92%;" pattern="/.app/">
```

Thanks you for your help.

### **EDIT**

I have resolved my problem with a jQuery check and a html 5 pattern

JS:

```
// If the user login doesn't finish by .app, we add them
            if(!$('input[name=user_login]').val().match('[.]app$'))
               $('input[name=user_login]').val($('input[name=user_login]').val() + '.app');
```

HTML5:

```
<input type="text" name="user_login"
placeholder="firstname.app" required style="width:92%;"
pattern=".*\.app">
```

Comment: With only HTML? It's easily hackable..

Comment: @Mr.Alien Most often it's convenient for the user to have an immediate warning, even if it doesn't replace the server side validation.

Comment: Yes I know, but a second test is maked after the submit (in php)

Comment: @dystroy yes, but some tend to validate with HTML5 instead of JavaScript thinking the older browsers will manage well, so thought I should just warn :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few differences between regex in JavaScript and in HTML attributes :

- you don't have to put your regex between `/`, contrary to js regex literals
- the start and end are implicit, so here you should add `.*` to match the start

You also forgot to escape the dot.

All in one, you probably want this :

```
<input type="text" name="user_login"
placeholder="firstname.app" required style="width:92%;"
pattern=".*\.app">
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/hicob/1/)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if($('input[name="user_login"]').val().indexOf(".app") >= 0){
  //code
}
```

or pattern:

```
<input type="text" name="user_login" placeholder="firstname.app" required style="width:92%;" pattern="\w*.app">
```

[Here is demo](http://jsbin.com/livuwano/1/edit?output)

Comment: giving alternate suggestion is not a bad thing I think :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by specifying the specific pattern:

```
<input type="text" 
name="user_login" 
placeholder="firstname.app" 
required style="width:92%;" 
pattern="[A-Za-z-0-9]+\.app">
```